# React Native keyboard Flickering

Tags: react-native, keyboard, state, flicker, persist

My React Native app Having Two_Tabs in Material Top Bar Navigation where first tab Entry-item and second search-items while typing flicker focusing to second tab search bar/input.(Both auto_Focus).
(Both autofocus numeric flicker)

I have tried all text-input/Search-Bar components from native-paper, react-native, Material etc..  Also tried react-native-spacer good for keyboard but will_unmount not found error so not useful in case.
(Both Focus on open but first default alphanumeric than numeric)

As the Second tab of Top Bar navigator input has ref.focus() to input while typing automatically then the keyboard flickers Switching Tabs.()
(Both Focus on open but first default alphanumeric than numeric)

Here I'm using searchBar of react_native_paper:

```
<Searchbar
      inputMode={"numeric"} //decimal good but secureTextEntry below treats as passcode
      // secureTextEntry={true}
      ref={inputref}
      //  removeClippedSubviews= {true}
      style={{ borderRadius: 5, padding: 10, fontSize: 25 }}
      onChangeText={(text) => searchHandler(text) && setLoadingbar(true)}
      onBlur={() => inputref.current?.focus()}
      placeholder="Enter Number feed"
      // blurOnSubmit="true"
      value={setSearchValues}
      //  loading={loadingbar}
      // onChange={}
      // keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'
      maxLength={10}
    />
```